# WAP to calculate the total marks of student in percentage if marks are (78,45,62)out of 100

Tags: java, operators

```
Class ANS
 public static void main(string []args);
 Int.doubleval=("78+45+62"*(100%)/100));

System.out.printIn(??)
```

//I can't figure out after this.

Comment: What language its this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double percentage=(78+45+62)/3;
    System.out.println(percentage);
}
```

Comment: It's divided by 100 not 3

Comment: @atikantvashishtha it's divided by 300 and then multiplied by 100 like this (a+b+c)*100/300 since each subject max marks is 100 and there are three subjects.